# Two Translation files with different domains, inside one template

Tags: symfony, translation

Help me go through this, I'm counting on you!
I have split my translation file into two files.
nav.fr.xlf & body.fr.xlf
Both have the same structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
        <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
            <body>
                <trans-unit id="1">
                    <source>Hello</source>
                    <target>Salut</target>
                </trans-unit>
</body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

The second one is the same, (same id for trans-unit)
in one twig file I have this

```
{% trans_default_domain "body" %}
```

and in the second one :

```
{% trans_default_domain "nav" %}
```

With only one translation Catalogue, it works fine, but with both : I have this error

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("[ERROR 1871] Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}b': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}g, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}bpt, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}ept, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}ph, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}it, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}x, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}bx, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}ex ). (in /usr/share/nginx/www/gitneargood/web/ - line 212, column 0) [ERROR 1871] Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}b': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}g, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}bpt, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}ept, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}ph, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}it, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}mrk, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}x, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}bx, {urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}ex ). (in /usr/share/nginx/www/gitneargood/web/ - line 213, column 0)") in "ngNrBundle:Welcome:nav.html.twig" at line 40." at app/cache/prod/classes.php line 5131 
Context: {"exception":"Object(Twig_Error_Runtime)"}
```

Please help me go through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem is solved, Shouldn't have used html tag inside a translation source/ target
Edit:
Well of course Xlf files are XML files and inserting html tags breaks the syntax.
What you can do is replacing < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;` and use the raw filter in twig.

Something like:

```
'<strong>Hello</strong>'|trans|raw
```

Comment: not sure about xliff, but with yaml translations we were using HTML tags, with wrapping whole message in quotes, i.e. `'Some <b>translation</b>'` worked fine for us.